# User Id from AWS Cognito User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm looking forward to use AWS Cognito User Pool in my application.
And have several questions:

1. Is it possible to store some sensitive data in Cognito: for example user permissions (I think no, because user can read and write data about himself - but I want to be sure)
2. How to get/add Id(to be used as external key) to user record? I have several options:

   a. Leverage username - but I wanted to use random string as ids; and even I fill username this way and enable aliasing for logging in - this field still client-side populated - so I have no control over it.

   b. Add custom field - how/where to properly populate it?

   c. Use `sub` field of access token - there is no proper way to get it - except base64-decoding access token - that looks hacky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Currently Cognito User pools attributes do not support this use case. You can use Cognito sync and create a dataset. You can configure your role in way that user does not have access to this sensitive dataset.
2. For #b you can find the custom attributes in attributes section of User pool configuration. You can make the attribute immutable by un-checking the mutable option. Note that, this will not enforce uniqueness for your custom id. 'sub' field from Id token might be the best option, as it enforces uniqueness as well. Making it available without parsing the token might be something to be considered as feature and it can be requested on AWS forums.

Comment: Are there any guidelines how to format feature request/proposition? Thanks

Comment: Note that (1) `sub` will change when you migrate users, (2) custom attributes cannot be added to access tokens. We are facing the same issue and haven't found a good solution.